# google sheet - script / conditional formatting > to set background color of columns based on date 1/ before today = red 2/ today = yellow

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, background-color, gs-conditional-formatting

I would like to set the background color of each columns based on the date: 
1/ before today = light red 
2/ today = yellow

How's my sheet? Like this

[image]

Dates are in row 6. The number representinf the day of the month (1, 2, 3, etc.) is an actual date but I changed the format so it only the day appears.

I want the highlight / background color to start from row 6 and to go all the way down, so I now what in my calendar belongs to the past, and what is happening today.

Some cells are empty below the date, so it makes it difficult for the conditional formatting to be functioning.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.... thanks to that post 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/kMc7bqNSJVY/ukAmmNvW2ScJ

I use for 
1/ `=$6:$6<today()` 
2/ `=$6:$6=today()`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9MrZ.png